# Manipulate post body of httpsampler before request

Tags: jmeter

I'm testing an Eclipse-RAP application with JMeter.
In RAP the client (javascript-framework in the browser) communicates with the server over a json-based protocol.

A message looks like this:

```
{"head":{"requestCounter":3,"uiSessionId":"832834"},"operations":[["set","w1",{"bounds":    [0,0,1680,893],"cursorLocation":[1262,-1]}]]}
```

As you see there is a session-ID stored in `uiSessionId. I extracted this id using a "Regular Expression Extractor" and stored it in a variable named`UI_SESSION_ID`.
Then i edited the raw "Post Body" of the recorded HTTP-Request:

```
{"head":{"requestCounter":3,"uiSessionId":"${UI_SESSION_ID}"},"operations":[["set","w1",{"bounds":    [0,0,1680,893],"cursorLocation":[1262,-1]}]]}
```

and it works.

But i have to alter each Post-Body of each HTTP-Request which can be a lot.
After some research i thought using a "BeanShell PreProcessor" would be the right thing, but:

```
var sampler = ctx.getCurrentSampler();
```

would give me a HTTPSampler and i did not find any method which allows me to retrieve the post-body, replace the session-id with the variable and set the altered post-body.
JavaDoc: http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSampler.html

Do you know any way i can replace the `uiSessionId` with the variable without changing every request manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to. The `uiSessionId` header has been introduced in a milestone version in preparation for multiple browser-tab support in RAP, but it has been replaced by another mechanism that does not use this header parameter anymore.

As of RAP 2.1 RC1, the client now attaches a “connection id” to every POST request in a URL parameter `cid`. This parameter does not affect load tests, and you don't have to remove it from your recording. Since every jmeter thread gets its own HttpSession, it's not a problem that all threads have the same cid.

One reason for this change was the ability to load test RAP applications without the kind of problems that you've been struggling with.